# Problems Deploying App to Ruby on Rails (no problems in development though)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production, puma

tl;dr
My app won't successfully deploy to Heroku after making some UI updates. The app works without any hiccups on my local device, though.

I followed a tutorial (https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts) through to the end. I was able to deploy the site successfully throughout the tutorial to Heroku.

However, after making some changes to the UI (and adding some images to my assets/images folder), I'm no longer able to successfully deploy the application. I've ran "rake assets:precompile" and can now get the app to successfully build in Heroku.

But when I try to load the app in Heroku, I get these error messages in the logs. Can I get some help on deploying this? Would this issue be able to be resolved if I hosted it on AWS? I've worked in Django before but not Rails.

Listed below is the error log from Heroku. These are, as far as I can tell, the more important error messages are

```html
2017-12-31T04:20:11.298411+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2017-12-31T04:20:14.840649+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] Puma starting in cluster mode...
2017-12-31T04:20:14.840675+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.3.4-p301), codename: Private Caller
2017-12-31T04:20:14.840676+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2017-12-31T04:20:14.840677+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Environment: production
2017-12-31T04:20:14.840677+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Process workers: 2
2017-12-31T04:20:14.840678+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Preloading application
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223050+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] ! Unable to load application: LoadError: cannot load such file -- fog
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223133+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: puma (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/puma)
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223190+00:00 app[web.1]: LoadError: cannot load such file -- fog
```

&&

```html
2017-12-31T04:21:31.835336+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fathomless-island-79606.herokuapp.com request_id=1beb0568-2805-4108-8f19-83904ee539f1 fwd="68.109.176.138" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

--- Entire Log Message ---

```html
2017-12-31T04:20:07.305986+00:00 app[api]: Deploy a43d564d by user xxxxx@xxxxx.xxxx
2017-12-31T04:19:44.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-12-31T04:20:07.732043+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-12-31T04:20:11.298411+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2017-12-31T04:20:14.840649+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] Puma starting in cluster mode...
2017-12-31T04:20:14.840675+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.3.4-p301), codename: Private Caller
2017-12-31T04:20:14.840676+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2017-12-31T04:20:14.840677+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Environment: production
2017-12-31T04:20:14.840677+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Process workers: 2
2017-12-31T04:20:14.840678+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Preloading application
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223050+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] ! Unable to load application: LoadError: cannot load such file -- fog
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223133+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: puma (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/puma)
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223190+00:00 app[web.1]: LoadError: cannot load such file -- fog
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223194+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223195+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223195+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223196+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223197+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:122:in `eager_load_fog'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223197+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:137:in `fog_credentials='
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223198+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223198+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:159:in `configure'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223199+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.1.0/lib/carrierwave.rb:14:in `configure'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223200+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223200+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223201+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223201+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223201+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223202+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:655:in `block in load_config_initializer'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223202+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223203+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in `load_config_initializer'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223203+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223203+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223204+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223204+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223204+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223205+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223205+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223206+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223206+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223206+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223207+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223207+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `each'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223207+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `tsort_each_child'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223208+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223209+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223209+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223209+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223210+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223210+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223211+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223211+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223211+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223212+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223212+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223212+00:00 app[web.1]:   config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223215+00:00 app[web.1]:   config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223216+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223216+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223217+00:00 app[web.1]:   config.ru:in `new'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223217+00:00 app[web.1]:   config.ru:in `<main>'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223218+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223218+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223219+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223219+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:313:in `load_rackup'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223220+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:242:in `app'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223221+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/runner.rb:138:in `load_and_bind'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223221+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/cluster.rb:391:in `run'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223222+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:174:in `run'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223222+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/cli.rb:77:in `run'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223223+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223224+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/puma:22:in `load'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.223224+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/puma:22:in `<top (required)>'
2017-12-31T04:20:17.469078+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-12-31T04:20:17.512006+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-12-31T04:20:17.514131+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-12-31T04:20:22.036948+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2017-12-31T04:20:25.691539+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] Puma starting in cluster mode...
2017-12-31T04:20:25.691555+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.3.4-p301), codename: Private Caller
2017-12-31T04:20:25.691556+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2017-12-31T04:20:25.691557+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Environment: production
2017-12-31T04:20:25.691578+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Process workers: 2
2017-12-31T04:20:25.691579+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Preloading application
2017-12-31T04:20:27.830859+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] ! Unable to load application: LoadError: cannot load such file -- fog
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844160+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: puma (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/puma)
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844174+00:00 app[web.1]: LoadError: cannot load such file -- fog
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844175+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844176+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844177+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844177+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844178+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:122:in `eager_load_fog'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844179+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:137:in `fog_credentials='
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844180+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844180+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:159:in `configure'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844181+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.1.0/lib/carrierwave.rb:14:in `configure'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844182+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844182+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844183+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844184+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844184+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844185+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:655:in `block in load_config_initializer'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844186+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844186+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in `load_config_initializer'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844187+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844187+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844188+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844188+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844189+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844190+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844190+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844191+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844191+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844192+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844193+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844193+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `each'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844194+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `tsort_each_child'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844195+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844195+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844196+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844197+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844197+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844198+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844199+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844199+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844200+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844200+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844201+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844202+00:00 app[web.1]:   config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844206+00:00 app[web.1]:   config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844206+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844207+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844208+00:00 app[web.1]:   config.ru:in `new'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844209+00:00 app[web.1]:   config.ru:in `<main>'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844209+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844210+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844211+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844211+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:313:in `load_rackup'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844212+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:242:in `app'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844212+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/runner.rb:138:in `load_and_bind'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844213+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/cluster.rb:391:in `run'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844214+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:174:in `run'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844214+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/cli.rb:77:in `run'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844215+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844216+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/puma:22:in `load'
2017-12-31T04:20:27.844216+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/puma:22:in `<top (required)>'
2017-12-31T04:20:28.026943+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-12-31T04:20:28.020460+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-12-31T04:21:33.265574+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=xxxxxxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=xxxxxxx fwd="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-12-31T04:21:31.835336+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=xxxxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=xxxxxxxxx fwd="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: where are you saving the images with carrierwave? Are you using aws? fog is for when you wanna save stuff on cloud services.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I run into problems with Heroku and Rails, I doublecheck a couple of things: 1. Make sure I push everything to whatever repository and then push to Heroku. 2. Make sure I run db:migrate 3. Make sure that I've added the necessary config vars to Heroku. In your case, though, there seems like there's an issue with fog: 
`2017-12-31T04:20:17.223190+00:00 app[web.1]: LoadError: cannot load such file -- fog` 
I'm not familiar with that gem, but if it requires login info, make sure you add it to Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars